# Display Number of Rows based on input parameter

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_max_rows (
    max_rows IN  NUMBER DEFAULT 1000
)
IS
    CURSOR cur_test ( max_rows IN number ) IS
        SELECT id FROM test_table
        WHERE user_id = 'ABC'
        AND ROWNUM <= max_rows;
    id test_table.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_test(max_rows) ;
    LOOP
    FETCH cur_test  INTO id;
    EXIT WHEN cur_test%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID:' || id);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

My requirement is to modify the above code so that when I pass -1 for max_rows, the proc should return all the rows returned by the query. Otherwise, it should limit the rows as per max_rows.

For example:

```
EXECUTE test_max_rows(-1);
```

This command should return all the rows returned by the SELECT statement above.

```
EXECUTE test_max_rows(10);
```

This command should return only 10 rows.

Comment: I suggest to remove the DEFAULT 1000 then. You won't need this -1 hack after that. Tell your application that uses this procedure to say that it needs 1000. Because any other solution with current select would induce an IF statement and another subquery to determine how many rows are in the table, eg. IF max_rows == -1 THEN max_rows = SELECT count(1) FROM table ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `OR` clause; change:

```
    AND ROWNUM <= max_rows;
```

to:

```
    AND (max_rows < 1 OR ROWNUM <= max_rows);
```

Then passing zero, -1, or any negative number will fetch all rows, and any positive number will return a restricted list. You could also replace the `default 1000` clause with `default null`, and then test for null instead, which might be a bit more obvious:

```
    AND (max_rows is null OR ROWNUM <= max_rows);
```

Note that which rows you get with a passed value will be indeterminate because you don't have an `order by` clause at the moment.

Doing this in a procedure also seems a bit odd, and you're assuming whoever calls it will be able to see the output - i.e. will have done `set serveroutput on` or the equivalent for their client - which is not a very safe assumption. An alternative, if you can't specify the row limit in a simple query, might be to use a pipelined function instead - you could at least then call that from plain SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_max_rows (max_rows IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL)
RETURN sys.odcinumberlist PIPELINED
AS
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (
        SELECT id FROM test_table
        WHERE user_id = 'ABC'
        AND (max_rows IS NULL OR ROWNUM <= max_rows)
    ) LOOP
        PIPE ROW (r.id);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And then call it as:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(test_max_rows);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(test_max_rows(10));
```

[Here's a quick SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f4dd/1). But you should still consider if you can do the whole thing in plain SQL and PL/SQL altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I didn't get what @TVM suggested. Pardon my ignorance. New to SQL.

Comment: @WamglindCarmasaic - I think tvm meant to remove the default clause and make the client *always* specify a number of rows; i.e. so it has to pass a really high value to make sure all rows are included. That implies your client knows enough about the data to do that safely, or runs a query first to decide what number to use.